# Android - Tracking multiple actions in an IntentService

Tags: android, asynchronous, broadcastreceiver

How can I keep track of 'N' number of tasks - specifically when all N of them have completed and whether any tasks failed.

For example, I have a service which can respond to 5 unique Intents to download 5 unique pieces of data from a remote server. I also have a requirement to download all 5 pieces of data at once.  Rather than duplicating code to download data, it would be nice to launch 5 Intents to download all of the data thus making use of the individual use-cases.

The problem I have is I need to know when all 5 download attempts have been made. I cannot keep track of which downloads have been made in the service because I am using an IntentService.  The same problem exists for BroadcastReceivers in that they exist only for the duration of their onReceive method.

I was looking at sendOrderedBroadcast, but this would require having a BroadCastReceiver for each download attempt. I have also [read](https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/tag/sendorderedbroadcast/) the result is created when sending is completed, but not therefore when the download would have completed?

> "If the resultReceiver argument is non-null it specifies a
>   BroadcastReceiver whose onReceive() method will be invoked when the
>   **sending of the ordered broadcast Intent completes**."

Perhaps I could try using an sendOrederedBroadcast and package up some kind of counter in the Intent which is passed around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution that is really quite neat and doesn't appear to break any Android paradigms.

**Overview**
Imagine an IntentService which responds to six actions. Five of these actions download some data and the sixth action is a request to download all data in one go. The original problem was how to reuse the logic to download the five items when responding to the action to download all items. There was also a requirement to receive a notification when all 5 downloads have been performed.

**Solution**
When responding to the action to download all data, the IntentService constructs an ArrayList containing the Intent Strings relating to each download action the service can perform. The IntentService effectively calls itself passing in the ArrayList of downloads to perform.  Each time the service performs a download it can "pop off" the first entry in the ArrayList and then call itself again.

The ArrayList does not have to contain all 5 downloads, it could be a subset of all the available downloads!  Each download attempt could also launch any Intents communicating individual success or failure without interrupting the flow of the download 'chain' or the final notification. In the end very little code was needed to solve this problem.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent aIntent) {
        String action = aIntent.getAction();
        // Data the service was called with.
        Bundle incomingData = aIntent.getExtras();
        // Data used to launch any new Intents.
        Bundle outgoingData = new Bundle(); 
        Intent result = null;

        if (ACTION_DOWNLOAD_ALL.equals(action)) {

              ArrayList<String> pendingDownloads = new ArrayList<String>();

              // This could contain any number of downloads, does not have to be all 5.
              pendingDownloads.add(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_1);    
              pendingDownloads.add(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_2);         
              pendingDownloads.add(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_3);
              pendingDownloads.add(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_4);
              pendingDownloads.add(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_5);

              // This will be the first download in the 'chain' to kick things off.
              result = new Intent(pendingDownloads.get(0));

              // Add the list of downloads to the Intent
              outgoingExtras.putStringArrayList("downloads", pendingDownloads);
              result.putExtras(outgoingExtras);

              // Start the download 'chain'.
              startService(result);

        } 
        else if (ACTION_DOWNLOAD_1.equals(action)) {
            // ... Do download #1.
            processDownloadChain(incomingData);
        }
        else if (ACTION_DOWNLOAD_2.equals(action)) {
            // ... Do download #2.
            processDownloadChain(incomingData);            
        }
        else if (ACTION_DOWNLOAD_3.equals(action)) {
            // ... Do download #3.
            processDownloadChain(incomingData);
        }
        else if (ACTION_DOWNLOAD_4.equals(action)) {
            // ... Do download #4.
            processDownloadChain(incomingData);
        }
        else if (ACTION_DOWNLOAD_5.equals(action)) {
            // ... Do download #5.
            processDownloadChain(incomingData);            
        }
}

private void processDownloadChain(Bundle incomingData) {

        if (incomingData != null) {

            // Get the list of downloads.
            ArrayList<String> downloads = incomingData
                    .getStringArrayList("downloads");

            if (downloads != null) {

                // Remove the handled download request from the 'chain'.
                downloads.remove(0);

                if (downloads.size() > 0) {
                    // Have another download request to handle.
                    Intent result = new Intent(downloadIntents.get(0));
                    Bundle outgoing = new Bundle();

                    outgoing.putStringArrayList("downloads", downloads);
                    result.putExtras(outgoing);
                    startService(result);
                } else {
                    // All downloads have been processed.
                    // Could notify BroadcastReceiver here.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The check for null in the private method processDownloadChain(...) is what allows the individual download actions to continue to be performed by the IntentService i.e. the IntentService still responds as normal to download actions.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manage a number of threads, using thread pool executor instead might prove helpful,

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

Start the same service per download request that starts a new async task that binds and unbinds to itself in onPreExecute / onPostExecute & onCancelled.

I don't know if you can bind a service to itself, would be fun if you could...